# css code not working because of firefox latest version

Tags: html, css

I have a problem in my coding which was working fine with an older version of Firefox. When I updated to Firefox 3.6 my vertical menu's first list is bigger than the other list.

Here is my CSS code;

```
#verti 
{
float:bottom;
width:300px;
margin-top:50px;
position:relative;
}

#verti ul li
{
position:relative;  
list-style:none;
} 

#verti ul
{
padding:0;
margin:0;
}

#verti li
{
height:2m;
width:9em;
background:#38ACEC;
margin-bottom:9px;
position:relative;
top:170px;
-moz-border-radius:80px;
border-radius:80px;
text-align:center;
}
```

Comment: http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/

Comment: check this link dude: jsfiddle.net/KyRus/17 the list name internal is not in its position

Comment: You say you updated to FF3.6. Are you aware FF is at version 11, now? You're markup does not work correctly in any other browser so looking to FF having an issue is barking up the wrong tree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you forget properties of  `#verti li height:2m;` is not correct

correct is

```
  #verti li
    {
    height:2em;
```

Check to your css ...

Comment: <div id="verti">
<ul>
    <li><a href="#1">Internal</a></li>
    <li><a href="#2">Publication</a></li>
    <li><a href="#3">Demos</a></li>
    <li><a href="#4">Achievements</a></li>
    <li><a href="#5">Career</a></li>
    <li><a href="#6">About us</a></li>
</ul>
</div>

Comment: it shows background colors are even...but for me in my output the first one is bigger then other it is not looking even for me...

Comment: check this link dude:  http://jsfiddle.net/KyRus/17/  the list name internal is not in its position

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at http://jsfiddle.net/wZABk/ . I have removed 
`top:170px;`.

Comment: i have another issue here chk this link http://jsfiddle.net/wZABk/4/
i cant place the list to its assigned background