# links not woking in horizontal menus

Tags: jquery, html, css

My horizontal links are not working properly after adding an auto-slider using `JQuery`
except `aerospace` and `automotive`. Add some more hyperlinks as I was unable to post more href links because of my reputation.

Below is my jquery code:

```
function slideSwitch() {
var $active = $('#slideshow IMG.active');

if ( $active.length == 0 ) $active = $('#slideshow IMG:last');
var $next =  $active.next().length ? $active.next()
    : $('#slideshow IMG:first');
var $sibs  = $active.siblings();
var rndNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * $sibs.length );
var $next  = $( $sibs[ rndNum ] );
$active.addClass('last-active');
$next.css({opacity: 0.0})
    .addClass('active')
    .animate({opacity: 1.0}, 1000, function() {
        $active.removeClass('active last-active');
    });
}

$(function() {
setInterval( "slideSwitch()", 5000 );
});
```

Html:

```
<div id="hori">
   <ul>
      <li><a href="/home/adapco/Desktop/ksa1" target="name">Aerospace</a></li>
      <li><a href="/home/adapco/Desktop/ksa2.css" target="name">Automotive</a></li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

css:

```
#slideshow
{
position:relative;
height:500px;
right:-570px;
top:-350px
}

#slideshow img
{
position:absolute;
top:0;
left:0;
z-index:8;
}

#slideshow img.active
{
z-index:10;
}

#slideshow img.last-active
{
z-index:9;
}
```

check this link http://jsfiddle.net/KyRus/20/

Comment: The #Slideshow DIV is overlapping the menu, which means the links are UNDER the div, and therefore not clickable...

Comment: check this link http://jsfiddle.net/KyRus/20/

Comment: @marco:not clear with ur message

Comment: Added it as an answer so you can close the thread :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a div with id "slideshow" which contains some images. 
This DIV is positined absolute ONTOP of the menu links - therefore you can't press the links. So you either need to position the slideshow different, or make the menu position absolute also.

Hope it helps :)

Comment: i want to display my webpage in all the browser versions...my code is working fine in mozill and chrome but not working properly in internet explorer.
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
is there any thing i can do by changing the above format,currently iam working in netbeans(redhat linux)

Comment: IE is different when interpretate CSS different sadly. Changing the meta declaration won't change that. You could make some IE specific CSS, but generel its a better idea to use better CSS in the first place.

Comment: ya sure @marco... i was unable to post the above question thats why i have to follow this way....

Comment: No problem. What exactly is the problem with IE. Can i ask why you are placing all elements in absolute/relative?

Comment: all the positions that i have mentioned in my css code is not properly executed when my page is viewed using IE.absolute:it will place the doc in exact location of a page.it doesn't affect other elements.if a position is relative then the user can define its position by left or right....

Comment: You should go accept the answers in the threads you created (press the sign left of the post which answered your question) so you can post new threads. It hard to see through this and everybody searching for something similar cant see the soloution.

Comment: i have started a new thread "making a webpage cross browser compatible"

Comment: Remember to also do it on the http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10025701/css-code-not-working-because-of-firefox-latest-version - as it seems you got your answer :)